# Difference between JOIN and multitable select in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE a (aid int);
CREATE TABLE b (bid int);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (2), (3), (4);
```

What would be the difference between

`SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE aid = bid;` and

`SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.aid=b.bid;`

The result of `explain analyze` for both queries looks totally same.

Comment: Use only `JOIN` syntax. Comma syntax is old and obsolete. With outer join you need to use error prone `*=` or `=*` operators.

Comment: @lad2025: There is not such operator `*=` or `=*` in (standard) SQL and definitely not in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `(+)=` or `*=` are Oracle/SQL Server specific. But it doesn't change the fact that the comma syntax join is obsolete and  should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Both queries do exactly **the same**.

Comment: I suspect you'll find the execution plan for both queries is identical

Comment: The JOIN is not "more efficient" - they are exactly the same. Neither one is "more efficient" than the other